# Java Call JasperReports print issue

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have made an application in Java. For the application bill receipt is required and I have used JasperReports (.jrxml ) file.

I have used JasperReports call in Java code for the generating bill.

When I click on print bill the print is not proper, size is reduced.

Actually the problem is strange. I am working on desktop computer and when I print from it , the print is ok.. but when I move my project to  other  system (say, Laptop) The print I get is approx 50% reduced than the original print. Is there any problem with iReport?

I have used below Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JRException,
        ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String reportSrcFile = "F:/Bills/FirstJasperReport.jrxml";

    // First, compile jrxml file.
    JasperReport jasperReport =    JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSrcFile);

    Connection conn = ConnectionUtils.getConnection();

    // Parameters for report
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport,
            parameters, conn);

    // Make sure the output directory exists.
    File outDir = new File("C:/jasperoutput");
    outDir.mkdirs();

    // PDF Exportor.
    JRPdfExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();

    ExporterInput exporterInput = new SimpleExporterInput(print);
    // ExporterInput
    exporter.setExporterInput(exporterInput);

    // ExporterOutput
    OutputStreamExporterOutput exporterOutput = new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(
            "C:/jasperoutput/FirstJasperReport.pdf");
    // Output
    exporter.setExporterOutput(exporterOutput);

    //
    SimplePdfExporterConfiguration configuration = new SimplePdfExporterConfiguration();
    exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
    exporter.exportReport();

    System.out.print("Done!");
}
```

How to resolve this issue

Comment: `When I click on print bill the print is not proper, size is reduced` - What do you mean? I think that problem in your report's template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. It is kind weird but when I search at [Jasper Community](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/803423/weird-printing-problem) I had found the solution

The code solved the problem

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet printRequestAttrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
printRequestAttrs.add(new PrinterResolution(600, 600, ResolutionSyntax.DPI)); // this resolution solved the problem
JRPrintServiceExporter exporter = new JRPrintServiceExporter();
exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, report);
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.PRINT_REQUEST_ATTRIBUTE_SET, printRequestAttrs);
exporter.setParameter(JRPrintServiceExporterParameter.DISPLAY_PRINT_DIALOG, Boolean.TRUE);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Hope this will help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the printer properties before printing? Maybe The size of your report template does not match with the paper size set on the printer.

Comment: Actually the problem is strange. I am working on desktop computer and when I print from it , the print is ok.. but when I move my project to  other  system (say, Laptop) The print I get is approx 50% reduced than the original print. Is there any problem with iReport? i also edited the question.